# Barcode input Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, barcode

When I open Sale(new) form it has an input field for a barcode scanner and a button add to add product items to this sale. As I understand it, if I connect a barcode scanner and focus on the input field it should automatically input readings from the barcode.

Now I have these readings (hopefully) and once the **add** button is pressed I don't really know what to do. I understand that I need to search the db and find the item with the same barcode. But the thing that is confusing me is that my Sale (new) is not saved yet therefore I can't add this item to the `SaleItem` model because I don't know the ID of the current sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has `accepts_nested_attributes_for` and `fields_for` for this situation:

```
# model
class Sale < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :sale_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sale_items
end
```

but you'll also have to write client-side code that will modify your form (there was a gem for that - `nested_form`, but it is a bit outdated), so that it posts data in form of `sale[sale_items_attributes][1][barcode]=12345`, `sale[sale_items_attributes][2][barcode]=4321`, and modify controller to permit these through strong parameters (`params.require(:sale).permit(... , sale_items_attributes:[:id, :barcode])`).

Trick is that rails will save nested models together with parent one, also nothing will be saved if validation is not passed for any of the models.

Comment: Thank you very much for helping, I ve got another question. Do I want to have an input field for the barcode and then track the 'ADD' button with JS, and once pressed take the value of the input and then preform a db search for the product and when found create a new sale_item record.

OR

Should the input be sale_item form with a submit button and once its pressed in create action I would do the search for the product and if found, save the record?